# Embedding a Form Builder page in another Wagtail page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

The Wagtail Form Builder documentation states:

> form_page.html differs from a standard Wagtail template in that it is
>   passed a variable `form`, containing a Django Form object, in addition
>   to the usual `page` variable.

But in my current project, I need to embed a contact form (implemented as a Form Builder page) in another page. In the model for that target page, I'm using a PageChooserPanel to let an editor select the form page to embed. In other words:

```
class TargetPage(Page):
    [...snip...]  
    contact_form = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        [...snip...]
        PageChooserPanel('contact_form', 'FormPage'),
    ]
```

My problem is in the template for the target page. I can access the attributes of the form page via `page.contact_form`, but since this page doesn't have a `form` object passed in, I can't figure out how to render my fields.

I am guessing that I need to override my target page's get_context() so that it includes the `form` object I need. But I can't figure out how to get that object. Can some kind soul put me on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

After a night's sleep, the answer turned out to be relatively obvious. The missing link is the get_form() method of a Wagtail FormPage. I'm now using this in my TargetPage model:

```
def attached_form(self):
    return self.contact_form.specific.get_form()
```

And thus, in my template, I can refer to attached_form to get my fields.

Comment: Could you please tell me if where do you put this method?

Comment: This goes in models.py, in the class for the page where you are including the FormPage.